# How do I set constraints and programmatically increase image in proportion to text size?

Tags: java, android, xml, image, constraints

This is perhaps a bit hard to explain, so I included a picture to show you what I mean.

I have three images in Android Studio. They should all be alined to match and the middle part should expand as the text on top of the graphic expands (the middle height should equal the text height I suppose). Have been sitting with this for awhile now but don't get anywhere.

1. Do I add code in xml? Something like android:layout_height="@id/textView"
2. Is it better to do relative constraints in xml or constraints in UI?
3. In xml, how do I do relative constraints to other children? I know code like android:layout_alignParentTop, android:layout_alignChildTop, but how do I set distance to children?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly, you want the centre image and text view to adjust height based on the height of the text. The simplest way of doing that would be using your middle image as a stretchable background to the text view and similarly for the header and footer views, preferably using 9-patch PNG images.

**Solution 1: Using 9-patch PNG images**

Here is an example XML with 9-patches to show how this works.

N.B. The example contains two layouts, each enclosing a single `TextView` with header and footer views.  The first `TextView` has a single line of text, the second has two lines.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="A line of text" 
        android:background="@drawable/middle" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom" />
</LinearLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="A line of text\nAnother line of text" 
        android:background="@drawable/middle" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Nine-Patches

top.9.png:

[image: Top]

middle.9.png:

[image: Middle]

bottom.9.png:

[image: Bottom]

Example output

[image: Example output]

**Solution 2: All XML**

Alternatively, you could do it all in XML using `<shape>` and `<layer-list>` drawables instead of the 9-patch PNG images.  Here is a modified version of the above to work with XML drawables.

This example shows rounded corners on the border as an added bonus, but beware it can be tricky to draw complex compound shapes using XML as there are only a small number of primitive shapes you can use.

Note also that this version relies on the addition of dimension resources to ensure everything matches up.

res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <dimen name="layout_width">320dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="header_height">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="header_inset_height">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="inset">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="inset_width">310dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="footer_height">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="corner_radius">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="inset_radius">5dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

res/drawable-nodpi/header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffff00ff" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <size 
                android:width="@dimen/layout_width" 
                android:height="@dimen/header_height" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="@dimen/inset"
        android:left="@dimen/inset"
        android:right="@dimen/inset">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff00" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="@dimen/inset_radius" 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <size 
                android:width="@dimen/inset_width" 
                android:height="@dimen/header_inset_height" />            
        </shape>        
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

res/drawable-nodpi/body.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffff00ff" />
            <size android:width="@dimen/layout_width"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="@dimen/inset"
        android:right="@dimen/inset">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff00" />
            <size android:width="@dimen/inset_width" />            
        </shape>        
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

res/drawable-nodpi/footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffff00ff" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
            <size 
                android:width="@dimen/layout_width" 
                android:height="@dimen/footer_height" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/inset"
        android:left="@dimen/inset"
        android:right="@dimen/inset">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff00" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="@dimen/inset_radius"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
            <size 
                android:width="@dimen/inset_width" 
                android:height="@dimen/header_inset_height" />            
        </shape>        
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

res/layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
            android:background="@drawable/header" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="A line of text" 
            android:background="@drawable/body" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_height"
            android:background="@drawable/footer" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
            android:background="@drawable/header" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="A line of text\nAnother line of text" 
            android:background="@drawable/body" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_height"
            android:background="@drawable/footer" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Example output:

[image: XML example output]

Comment: Wow, that was an amazing in-depth explanation! Thanks a bunch for taking the time, you've helped me a lot! :D

Comment: Is it better/possible to do it entirely in xml style though? With the same graphic layout?

Comment: It is possible in XML, but whether it is better or not is questionable.   I've updated the answer with a second, pure XML solution.  It looks quite nice with rounded corners.   I'll let you decide if this XML version is better for you.

Comment: Another amazing post, thanks a lot for your assistance! I'll certainly try out using only XML as well! :)

Comment: Glad if it helped.  It was useful to me to do the pure-XML solution, as that is not the way I had done it before, but it works nicely for simple borders.